# How does one travelling from Israel abroad (or vice versa) perform Shnayim Mikra when the parshiyot are out of sync?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, chutz-laaretz, shnayim-mikra

[Shulchan Aruch 285](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.285?lang=bi) codifies the obligation for each individual to read that week's *parshah*, the text twice and the (Aramaic) translation once.

In some years (e.g. this year, 5779) the *parshiyot* read in Israel and the Diaspora are one week out of sync for a number of weeks.

What does someone do when travelling from Israel to the Diaspora during this time? Would he have to read the *parashah* in the Diaspora a second time? Or maybe his reading the week before counts?

What does someone do when travelling from the Diaspora to Israel? Does he need to (at some point) read the *parashah* that he will miss hearing?

Does it make a difference if one knows that he will be returning home after his trip? Can he stick to his original schedule, despite being out of sync with where he is spending that *shabbat*?

Answer (score 2):

Many years ago I was advised by my Rabbi Z"l to read חוק לישראל. And I faced a similar problem. Here's what he told me:

There are two maps of reading Torah - personal and social:

- On the personal level, completing the whole Torah 2M1T has many Kaballic benefits (see the intro to חוק לישראל)
- On the public level, reading the Parasha in public is a different Mitzvah.

Therefore, independently of the traveling and Shabbos stayings, to achieve the personal goal **the cycle must be completed and one should schedule the 2M1T according to his own cycle**, trying to sync it with the public as much as possible, of course. (That depends on for how long one is staying abroad, how many weekly journeys he has and more.)

Comment: Aside from Kaballic benefits, it also enhances your simchas Yom Tov of Shemini Atzeres.

Comment: This is a great answer but does it hold only for Chok l'yisrael (which is a full-fledged learning seder in and of itself) or for echad targum v'2mikra in general?